# Do I need to upgrade to Kernel 4.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS on my Dell Inspiron 5548 with i5 and ATI Graphics AMD Radeon R7 M265 2GB DDR3. **(First I installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS then got automatically upgraded to 14.04.4 LTS but still my Kernel didn't got updated to 4.2)** Few weeks ago I tried to upgrade to Kernel 3.19 ubutnu, but it caused Kernel Panic. So downgraded it to previous 3.16. The Commands I used to do that are as below:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-vivid 

linux-image-virtual-lts-vivid --help

sudo apt-get install linux-image-virtual-lts-vivid

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get autoremove

lightdm

sudo lightdm

sudo apt-get install linux-image-virtual-lts-vivid

sudo login

sudo lightdm

sudo apt-get purge linux-image-virtual-lts-vivid

sudo apt-get purge linux-image-virtual-lts-vivid-tools*

sudo apt-get purge linux-image-lts-vivid-tools*

sudo apt-get purge linux-lts-vivid-tools*

sudo apt-get remove  linux-image-virtual-lts-vivid

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get update

sudo boot/grub/grub.cfg

sudo nautilus

sudo apt-get purge linux-lts-vivid-tools*

sudo update grub,cfg

sudo update grub.cfg

sudo update boot/grub/grub.cfg

sudo update-grub

sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-3.19.0-49 linux-headers-3.19.0-49-generic 

linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic

sudo apt-get purge linux-image-extra-3.19.0-49-generic 

sudo update-grub

sudo apt-get update
```

But I worked and I was able boot the system.

Today check my kernel version using:

```
uname -a
```

It shows following o/p:

**Linux EagleNest 3.16.0-70-generic #90~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 6 22:56:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux**

Is this latest kernel version for me? If not, then does my last attempt has caused any problem and prevented me from updating to latest kernel? And if this version is latest will I receive security update untill support lifetime of 14.04 LTS? Also Where can I check what is latest kernel version for my distribution?

Few users reported problem with upgrade to 4.2 like blank screen at boot instead of login screen, So is it worth to upgrade if the kernel that I have now is the latest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not have to upgrade to kernel 4.2, but you can do it.

The 3.16 kernel will get security updates till its EOL.

You can upgrade to kernel 4.2 by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

You can also upgrade to kernel 4.4 if you like by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Comment: Last-time upgrade to 3.19 caused Kernel Panic. Is there a same risk upgrading 4.2/4.4 i.e. the problem is device dependent? or these updates are stable? I mean should I rock my currently stable boat? Are there any benefits in doing so?

Comment: Does my last action removing 3.19 stopped further updates? Because I didn't received any updates after 3.16, is that okay or normal?

Comment: Please answer my other questions. For now I'll wait for new answers for 2 days and I don't receive answer answering all of my questions (at least most of them), then I confirm/accept this answer.

Comment: You can always boot with a previous kernel if anything goes wrong. Some proprietary drivers may not build with some kernels. If you have doubts, just leave the kernel as it is.

Comment: Yeah.. I am currenly using AMD proprietary display driver (AMD Catalyst, aka fglrx). So upgrading may not work (like last time for 3.19).. So for now I will stick to 3.16.. Thanks Pilot6!!